# Does 3D convolution in Keras work with RGB videos?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, video-processing

Keras' Conv3D expects input  `5D tensor with shape: (batch, conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3, channels)` (assuming data_format is "channels_last"). Now say my filter size is (3,3,3) and my input is (10,125,300,200,3), a video dataset of 10 videos, each with 125 frames, and spatial size 300x200,and channel 3 due to frames being RGB. The default stride value is `(1, 1, 1)`. The picture in my head of how this convolution works is as shown [here at 9:28](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQ67NBCLV98).

What I can't figure is whether the stride of 1 along the temporal dimension moves 1 frame at a time or 1 channel of a frame at a time. I tried to look up the code of conv3D [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L568-L602) and couldn't gather much. I tried training a deep learning network using 3D CNNS and RGB videos and the resulting images have messed up colours (almost grey), so I'm assuming there's some mess up with colour channels. I checked my input, that seems fine, so the network is probably funny.

Tl:dr

Need to figure if RGB videos need conscious changes in strides so the channels of one frame are treated with 2D convolution, and also would be grateful for pointers to code/papers dealing with RGB videos and 3D CNNs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all convolutions, the filter size encompasses all channels together. Channels do not participate in strides.

So, strides happen as if your video was a cube. Stride 1 step in each dimension (x,y,z) until the entire cube is swept. (The convolution has no idea of what the dimensions are, and will not treat the frames differently from how they treat pixels).

You have a little 3x3x3 cube sweeping a huge 125x300,200 parallelepiped, pixel by pixel, frame by frame. So: the stride moves one frame at a time, but considering only a 3x3 segment of the image.

This doesn't "seem" good for videos (but machine learning has its surprises), unless at some point you have a very tiny resolution, so that a filter starts seeing the whole picture in each frame.

You can keep testing the 3D convs to see what happens, but a few suggestions that "seem" better are:

- Use `TimeDistributed(Conv2D(...))` and `TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(...))` until you get a small resolution video in the middle of the model (or even a 1x1, if you're going extreme). Then start using:

  - `Conv3D` if there are still spatial dimensions
  - `Conv1D` if you eliminated the spatial dimensions
  - In both cases, it's a good idea to increase the kernel size in the frames dimension, 3 frames may be too little to interpret what is happening (unless you have a low frame rate)
- Use `TimeDistributed(Conv2D(...))`, eliminate the spatial dimensions at some point and start using RNNs like `LSTM`
- Use `ConvLSTM2D` layers.